# How to find SQL job which is aggregating data between 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, jobs, sql-job

So I got a list of jobs in my server and 2 tables that one of those jobs is aggregating. Lets say in table "A" there is a rows of purchase receipts, and in table "B" its info that is used by other procedures lets say purchase price/VAT/etc.. So my question is there a way to find which jobs uses that table or both of them? FYI I am using SQL server 2008 R2

Comment: A job can invoke anything that can invoke other stuff, etc. This makes it difficult to debug. On the other hand, you can add a trigger to the tables that record every access with data like `CONTEXT_INFO()` or `ORIGNIAL_LOGIN()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the table that stored SQL Agent job steps, but that only helps if each step makes a call directly to the table and doesn't just call a stored proc:

`select * from msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps where command like '%my_table%'`

Comment: And there are no functions, views or anything else that might hide the table usage. But this works great if all the sql is inline.